# Select in prepared statement returns date only

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to run code from this [webpage](https://simplesqlserver.com/2013/09/10/monitoring-database-and-table-sizes/) Part with tables, i have edited it so i'm taking date using `GETADATE()` unfortunately it ends with errors `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.` I commented out `Insert` statement and select returns only casted `@DateAdded` `(No column name) Oct 25 2017 10:56AM` Same code in parameterized version works ok, is there something wrong with the dynamic version?

```
    DECLARE @SQL NVarChar(max)
DECLARE @DateAdded SmallDateTime

SELECT @DateAdded = GETDATE()

SET @SQL = ' Use [?];
    DECLARE @DatabaseSize Float

    IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#TableSizes'') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
          DROP TABLE #TableSizes
    END

    SELECT DatabaseName = DB_NAME()
    , TableName = a2.name
    , SchemaName = a3.name
    , RowCounts = a1.rows
    , TableSizeMB = (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) / 128
    , DataSizeMB = a1.data / 128
    , IndexSizeMB = (CASE WHEN (a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used,0)) > a1.data 
                        THEN (a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used,0)) - a1.data 
                        ELSE 0 
                    END) /128
INTO #TableSizes
FROM (SELECT ps.object_id
            , [rows] = SUM(CASE
                                WHEN (ps.index_id < 2) THEN row_count
                                ELSE 0
                            END)
            , reserved = SUM(ps.reserved_page_count)
            , data = SUM(CASE
                            WHEN (ps.index_id < 2) 
                                THEN (ps.in_row_data_page_count + ps.lob_used_page_count + ps.row_overflow_used_page_count)
                            ELSE (ps.lob_used_page_count + ps.row_overflow_used_page_count)
                        END)
            , used = SUM (ps.used_page_count) 
        FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
        GROUP BY ps.object_id) AS a1
    INNER JOIN sys.all_objects a2  ON a1.object_id = a2.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas a3 ON a2.schema_id = a3.schema_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT it.parent_id
            , reserved = SUM(ps.reserved_page_count)
            , used = SUM(ps.used_page_count)
        FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
            INNER JOIN sys.internal_tables it ON it.object_id = ps.object_id
        WHERE it.internal_type IN (202,204)
        GROUP BY it.parent_id) AS a4 ON a4.parent_id = a1.object_id
WHERE a2.type <> ''S'' and a2.type <> ''IT''

    SELECT @DatabaseSize = Sum(TableSizeMB) FROM #TableSizes

    --INSERT INTO test..[Tables]
    SELECT ''' + Cast(@DateAdded as nvarchar(50)) + '''
        , DatabaseName
        , SchemaName
        , TableName
        , RowCounts
        , TableSizeMB
        , DataSizeMB
        , IndexSizeMB
        , (TableSizeMB/@DatabaseSize) * 100 
    FROM #TableSizes
    WHERE TableSizeMB > .005 * @DatabaseSize 
        AND TableSizeMB > 100

    DROP TABLE #TableSizes'

exec sp_MSforeachdb @SQL
```

Comment: the problem is type of first parameter of sp_MSforeachdb , it is nvarchar(2000), your script depending of date has length 2280+, the engine just cuts your query. You can make script shorter or use  command1, command2   and command3 parameters, all less 2000 charatcers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substring you query (2000 char max)

```
create proc sys.sp_MSforeachdb
    @command1 nvarchar(2000), @replacechar nchar(1) = N'?', @command2 nvarchar(2000) = null, @command3 nvarchar(2000) = null,
    @precommand nvarchar(2000) = null, @postcommand nvarchar(2000) = null
```

Try split on @command1 , @command2